# Example of a continious function in [-1,1] , not differentiable at 5 points.

Tags: calculus

is anybody that can answer the following exercise? "Define a continuous function in [-1,1] which isn´t differentiable at 5 different points."

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a function which is not differentiable at only 1 point?

Comment: Can you give an example of a continuous function which is not differentiable everywhere? :)

Comment: In the spirit of the Did, $\mathsf{VVV}$

Answer (score 1):

Pick $-1<x_1<\ldots <x_5<1$ and let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^5 |x-x_i|$.